# Converting a PHP array to JSON string

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array ( 
       [1] => Laravel 
       [2] => Volta 
       [3] => Web 
       [4] => Design 
       [5] => Development 
      )
```

Now I want to convert this array to a string that has to look like this

```
data: [{id: 1, text: 'Laravel'},{id: 2, text: 'Volta'},{id: 3, text: 'Web'},...],
```

Comment: You will have to convert the indexed list into subarrays each, if you want to split it into `id:` and `text:`. And the shallow answers are incorrect when it comes to the output syntax (unquoted keys), but presumably so are you.

Comment: when i do json_encode i get {"1":"Laravel","2":"Volta","3":"Web","4":"Design","5":"Development"}but i need {id: 1, text: 'Laravel'},{id: 2, text: 'Volta'},{id: 3, text: 'Web'}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOu can try

```
$data = Array(
        1 => "Laravel",
        2 => "Volta",
        3 => "Web",
        4 => "Design",
        5 => "Development"
);

array_walk($data, function (&$item, $key) {
    $item = array("id"=>$key,"text"=>$item);
});

print(json_encode(array("data"=>array_values($data))));
```

Output

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"text":"Laravel"},{"id":2,"text":"Volta"},{"id":3,"text":"Web"},{"id":4,"text":"Design"},{"id":5,"text":"Development"}]}
```

Comment: almost there thank you but is there a way to only get [{"id":1,"text":"Laravel"},{"id":2,"text":"Volta"},{"id":3,"text":"Web"},{"id":4,"text":"Design"},{"id":5,"text":"Development"}]

Answer (score 4):

use `json_encode`

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: This won't produce what is required

Comment: @RMcLeod that's why i commented to see `baba's` answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just use php's function `json_encode`

Comment: This doesn't provide the required output

Answer (score 1):

you can do that with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and with that you will be able to parset with javascript to show it to users